# How do I only upload the meta-data for the current version to Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane

When I want to use [fastlane supply](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/supply) to deploy the current version of the app to Google Play, all previous meta-data is uploaded:

```
Preparing to upload for language 'de-DE'...
Updating changelog for code version '431' and language 'de-DE'...
Updating changelog for code version '506' and language 'de-DE'...
[...]
Preparing to upload for language 'en-US'...
Uploading image file ./fastlane/metadata/android/en-US/images/icon.png...
Uploading image file ./fastlane/metadata/android/en-US/images/promoGraphic.png...
Updating changelog for code version '287' and language 'en-US'...
Updating changelog for code version '294' and language 'en-US'...
Updating changelog for code version '346' and language 'en-US'...
Updating changelog for code version '370' and language 'en-US'...
Updating changelog for code version '418' and language 'en-US'...
Updating changelog for code version '422' and language 'en-US'...
Updating changelog for code version '431' and language 'en-US'...
Updating changelog for code version '506' and language 'en-US'...
[...]
Preparing to upload for language 'fr-FR'...
Updating changelog for code version '431' and language 'fr-FR'...
Updating changelog for code version '506' and language 'fr-FR'...
[...]
Preparing apk at path 'app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk' for upload...
Updating changelog for code version '20800' and language 'de-DE'...
Updating changelog for code version '20800' and language 'en-US'...
Updating changelog for code version '20800' and language 'fr-FR'...
Updating track 'beta'...
Uploading all changes to Google Play...
Successfully finished the upload to Google Play
```

The only thing that actually changed was the APK and the changelog for the most recent version `20800` (via [gradle-android-git-version](https://github.com/gladed/gradle-android-git-version)).

Supplying the parameters `--skip_upload_metadata`, `--skip_upload_images`, and `--skip_upload_screenshots` suppresses the upload of all metadata, if I have understood correctly.

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: changelog, images and screenshots are all under the folder metadata, i would use `--skip_upload_images` and `skip_upload_screenshots` to upload only the apk and the changelog

Comment: @wael gabsi if I add skip images/screenshots, fastlane will still update the changelogs of every version as shown in the output from the script.